# how do I change shortcut number in pie menu?

Tags: interface, customization, pie-menu

[image: pie menu]

the image is the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> pie menu but my question is about pie menus in general.

You can see there are numbers next to each pie menu button.

I'd like to customize the numbers (I think those are kind of random?). Is it possible?

Thank you.

Comment: Hello. I don't know if you can customize these shortcuts but I think the numbers are not random but follow the layout of the [numpad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numeric_keypad)